# centos mysql keeps crashing, what to do?

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, sql, dedicated-server

I recently got a dedicated server under CentOS with OVH. Everything has been working fine since 2 months, but starting a few days ago mysql keeps crashing and that causes various problems with my forum.

What do I need to do to start investigating? Is there a log file somewhere that will tell me why mysql crashed? Can I know the server load when mysql crashed, or if the server was executing a slow query?

Every time I check the server load seems to be fine (equals or under 1).

My server = i3 2130 / 2 cores / 8gb ram / dedicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check under /var/lib/mysql for .err files.**

**Turn off MySQL and run repair commands:**

1. Identify all corrupted tables using myisamchk

   myisamchk /var/lib/mysql/bugs/*.MYI >> /tmp/myisamchk_log.txt
2. Repair the corrupted table using myisamchk

   myisamchk -r profiles.MYI
3. Perform check and repair together for entire MySQL database

   myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state /var/lib/mysql/bugs/*.MYI

We need more information to better help you. Ideally, you might want to hire a DB admin to avoid data loss or more corruption.

You might have a bad drive.
You might need to also run fsck.
You might have bad RAM.

Honestly, there are so many things that could be causing this. I would hire an admin.

Comment: Where can i hire an admin for cheap ?

Comment: Google. Theres solidshellsecurity.com and rack911.com for examples. But quality does not come cheap.

Comment: I just remembered i have changed ft_min_word_len to 3 (it was 4 by default) a couple of days ago.... could it be the source of my problem ?

Comment: Also i am getting this error when trying to run myisamchk commands : myisamchk: error: File '/var/lib/mysql/bugs/*.MYI' doesn't exist

Comment: You need to specify the correct path.